# how to use more than one ps in distributed tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, distributed

I am trying to run the [distributed tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception/inception). But I have some troubles.
Firstly, it can process 35 images/sec on a single GPU(GTX TITAN X),single host(intel E5-2630 v3), however running it with the distributed code can only process 26 images/sec each process on 4 GPUs ,single host. Moreover, it can process 8.5 images/sec on 2 hosts, each with 4 GPUs. So the performance of this distributed version seems very poor. Could anybody give me some suggestions that why I got such a poor result. 
Secondly, I wonder whether more ps server can improve the performance. So I tried to use 2 ps server, the program was blocked with log info :

> CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:ps/replica:0/task:1

I ran the program on the slurm system, so I used the python multiprocessing model to start the ps server.

```
def get_slurm_env():
    node_list = expand_hostlist(os.environ['SLURM_NODELIST'])
    node_id = int(os.environ['SLURM_NODEID'])
    tasks_per_node = int(os.environ['SLURM_NTASKS_PER_NODE'])

    # It is difficult to assign the port and gpu id in slurm env.
    # The assigned gpu in different host is not always the same, and you nerver know 
    # which gpu is assigned in another host.
    # Different slurm job may run in the same machine, so the port num may be conflict as well
    task_id = int(os.environ['SLURM_PROCID'])
    task_num = int(os.environ['SLURM_NTASKS'])
    visible_gpu_ids = os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'].split(',')
    visible_gpu_ids = [int(gpu) for gpu in visible_gpu_ids]
    worker_port_list=[FLAGS.worker_port_start + incr for incr in range(len(visible_gpu_ids))]

    FLAGS.worker_hosts = ["%s:%d" % (name, port) for name in node_list for port in worker_port_list]
    assert len(FLAGS.worker_hosts) == task_num, 'Job count is not equal %d : %d' % (len(FLAGS.worker_hosts), task_num)

    FLAGS.worker_hosts = ','.join(FLAGS.worker_hosts)
    FLAGS.ps_hosts = ["%s:%d" % (name, FLAGS.ps_port_start) for name in node_list]
    FLAGS.ps_hosts = ','.join(FLAGS.ps_hosts)
    FLAGS.job_name = "worker"
    FLAGS.task_id = task_id
    os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = str(visible_gpu_ids[task_id%tasks_per_node])

def ps_runner(cluster, task_id):
    tf.logging.info('Setup ps process, id: %d' % FLAGS.task_id)
    os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = ""
    server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name="ps", task_index=task_id)
    server.join()
    tf.logging.info('Stop ps process, id: %d' % FLAGS.task_id)

def main(unused_args):
    get_slurm_env()

    # Extract all the hostnames for the ps and worker jobs to construct the
    # cluster spec.
    ps_hosts = FLAGS.ps_hosts.split(',')
    worker_hosts = FLAGS.worker_hosts.split(',')
    tf.logging.info('PS hosts are: %s' % ps_hosts)
    tf.logging.info('Worker hosts are: %s' % worker_hosts)

    cluster_spec = tf.train.ClusterSpec({'ps': ps_hosts,
                                   'worker': worker_hosts})
    if FLAGS.task_id == 0:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target = ps_runner, args = ({'ps': ps_hosts,'worker': worker_hosts}, 0))
        p.start()
    server = tf.train.Server(
        {'ps': ps_hosts,
         'worker': worker_hosts},
         job_name=FLAGS.job_name,
         task_index=FLAGS.task_id)

    # `worker` jobs will actually do the work.
    dataset = ImagenetData(subset=FLAGS.subset)
    assert dataset.data_files()
    # Only the chief checks for or creates train_dir.
    if FLAGS.task_id == 0:
        if not tf.gfile.Exists(FLAGS.train_dir):
            tf.gfile.MakeDirs(FLAGS.train_dir)
    tf.logging.info('Setup worker process, id: %d' % FLAGS.task_id)
    inception_distributed_train.train(server.target, dataset, cluster_spec)
```

Comment: I have solved the problem of multiple ps server for blocking. However, the performance of the program with multiple ps server was even poorer than singel ps server.

Answer (score 0):

Are you willing to consider MPI based solutions which do not require distributed memory specific changes to your code for distributed tensorflow? We have recently developed a version of user-transparent distributed tensorflow using MaTEx. https://github.com/matex-org/matex

We will be able to help you, should you face any problems.